# Why does integer_decode in Rust work that way?

Tags: rust, floating-point

I don't understand how integer_decode in `num_traits` works. For instance: we have

```
use num_traits::Float;

let num = 2.0f32;

// (8388608, -22, 1)
let (mantissa, exponent, sign) = Float::integer_decode(num);
```

But how we get those integers?

Binary representation of `2.0f32` has 0 sign bit, 1 bit as leading bit in exponent and mantissa consisting of zeros. How to get integer decode and why we choose this particular decomposition and not 8388608*2 as mantissa and -23 as exponent?

Comment: there is no integer_decode in rust std

Comment: What's unclear after reading [the source code](https://docs.rs/num-traits/latest/src/num_traits/float.rs.html#2027-2041)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't write the function, so take this answer with a grain of salt, as it's more of a gut feeling than knowledge. The rationale behind it is not explained in the comments in the function implementation, so unless the author of the code speaks up, we can't deliver more than educational guesses.

`f32` is based on IEEE-754, which specifies that a `2.0` shall be represented as the following three parts:

- the sign bit `0`

  - indicates that `2.0` is positive
- the exponent `128`

  - it's one byte that indicates the exponent, with `127` representing `0`. `128` means `1`
- the mantissa `0`

  - the mantissa consists of 23 bits and has an implicit `1.` in front of it. So `0` means `1.0`.

To get the actual number, you need to do `0 * (-1) + 2 ^ (128 - 127) * 1.0`, which is `2 ^ 1 * 1` = `2`.

---

Now this is not the only way to compute that. You could also do:

- map the sign bit to `1` and `-1`
- instead of prefixing the mantissa with `1.`, add a `1` in front of it, making it an integer. (this avoids having to use a float to decode a float, which is nonsense for obvious reasons)
- subtract `127` from the exponent, making it signed. Then, remove `23` from it to compensate that our mantissa is now shifted by `23` bits (because the mantissa is `23` bits long and we moved the comma all the way back to make it an integer).

This would, for `2.0` give us:

- sign `-1`
- mantissa `0b100000000000000000000000` = `8388608`
- exponent `128 - 127 - 23` = `-22`

Now we can do `sign * mantissa * 2 ^ exponent`, as specified in the [documentation](https://docs.rs/num-traits/latest/num_traits/float/trait.Float.html#tymethod.integer_decode) to get our value back.

Note how fast calculating those integers was: a binary decision for the sign, a binary `or` operation for the mantissa and a single `u8` subtraction for the exponent (a single one because one can combine `- 127 - 23` to `- 150` beforehand).

---

> why we choose this particular decomposition and not 8388608*2 as mantissa and -23 as exponent

The short version is that this guarantees that all possible mantissas can be treated the same way. It's `23` bits long and a `1` with the entire mantissa attached to it is always a valid integer. In the case of `0` this is a `1` with 23 `0`s, `0b100000000000000000000000`, which is `8388608`.

Answer (score 0):

[`integer_decode()`](https://docs.rs/num/latest/num/trait.Float.html#tymethod.integer_decode) documentation is quite clear:

> Returns the mantissa, base 2 exponent, and sign as integers, respectively. The original number can be recovered by `sign * mantissa * 2 ^ exponent`.

```
1 * 8388608 * 2^-22 == 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Mostly IEEE 754 uses this description of finite floating-point numbers: A floating-point number has the form (−1)<sup>*s*</sup>×*b*<sup>*e*</sup>×*m*, where:

- *s* is 0 or 1.
- *e* is any integer *e*<sub>min</sub> ≤ *e* ≤ *e*<sub>max</sub>.
- *m* is a number represented by a digit string of the form *d*<sub>0</sub>.*d*<sub>1</sub>*d*<sub>2</sub>…*d*<sub>*p*−1</sub> where *d*<sub>*i*</sub> is an integer digit 0 ≤ *d*<sub>*i*</sub> < *b*.

This form is described in IEEE-754 2019 clause 3.3. *b* is the base, *p* is the precision (number of digits in base *b*), and *e*<sub>min</sub> and *e*<sub>max</sub> are bounds on the exponent. This form is useful for certain things, such as describing the normalized form as starting with a leading “1.” or “0.” when the base is two. However, the standard also says, in the same clause:

> It is also convenient for some purposes to view the significand as an 10 integer; in which case the finite floating-point numbers are described thus:
>
> Signed zero and non-zero floating-point numbers of the form (−1)<sup>*s*</sup>×*b*<sup>*p*</sup>×*c*, where
>
> - *s* is 0 or 1.
> - *q* is any integer *e*<sub>min</sub> ≤ *q*+*p*−1 ≤ *e*<sub>max</sub>.
> - *c* is a number represented by a digit string of the form *d*<sub>0</sub>*d*<sub>1</sub>*d*<sub>2</sub>…*d*<sub>*p*−1</sub> where *d*<sub>*i*</sub> is an integer digit 0 ≤ *d*<sub>*i*</sub> ≤ *b* (*c* is therefore an integer with 0 ≤ *c* < *b*<sup>*p*</sup>).

(My reproduction of the IEEE-754 text changes some of the typography slightly.) Note two things. First, this matches the results `Float::integer_decode` gives you. In the `Float` format, *p* is 24, so *m* should have 24 bits, not 25, so it can be 8,388,608 (2<sup>23</sup>) and cannot be 16,777,216 (2<sup>24</sup>).

Second, what makes this form useful is *m* is always an integer and can be any integer in that range—the low digit of *m* is immediately to the left of the radix point, so the consecutive values representable in this range of the floating-point format are consecutive integers, and we can analyze them and write proofs using number theory.

You could use alternate forms that are mathematically equivalent but let the significand be 2<sup>24</sup>, but then the low digit in such a form would have to be zero (because there is no bit in the format to represent it having any other value), so it is not particularly useful.